# Check input when text is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I have a question about how to check when input text is changed? I use `keydown` like this:

```
$('#query').keydown(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

But when the actual value is `query`, the console will be log `quer`. It always delay. I dont know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 3 ways to implement it.

The first way is using other event such as `input` or `propertychange`. Notice that `propertychange` is supported only on IE and `input` is supported on modern browsers.

```
$('#query').on('input perpertychange', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

The second way is putting `console.log($(this).val());` in `setTimeout` statement. You can get what you're typing. (The reason? I'm sorry, I really dont know why, just use it);

```
$('#query').keydown(function () {
    var query = $(this);

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(query.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

And the last one is using `textchange` event (http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event). Like this:

```
$('#query').on('textchange', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `keydown` here but `keyup`, so that the value of the input has changed when you receive the event.

See the MDN on the [processing of key events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Processing_of_key_events).

Comment: I want to get the text when use press the button (it means press down, not only up the button)

Comment: The text when the user press the button hasn't changed and the browser has no idea of how the text will change *if* you release the key. To simulate what will happen after, you may insert the key at the cursor's position but that's not the right way. What's your goal ?

Comment: I create an autocomplete can detect when user's typing and I'll send request to server and it must be real time!

Comment: I don't see any problem in waiting for the key release as is done by other autocomplete implementations

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [keyup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup)

```
$('#query').keyup(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: But when I press the button but dont up the button, there's no log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('#query').change(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: When you blur the input, the `change` event will be fired!