# Event listener doesn't trigger after changing the input text by javascript

Tags: javascript

Event listener doesn't trigger after changing the input text by javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  var sampleInput = document.getElementById("sampleInput");
  
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    sampleInput.value = "text has been changed!";
  });
  
  sampleInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    console.log("(input) text has been changed!!");
  });
  
  sampleInput.addEventListener('textchange', (event) => {
    console.log("(textchange) text has been changed!!");
  });
  
  sampleInput.addEventListener('perpertychange', (event) => {
    console.log("(perpertychange) text has been changed!!");
  });
  
  sampleInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    console.log("(keydown) text has been changed!!");
  });
});
```

[Sample code - jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/gex71u92/1/)

I have tried to use the events listed here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824933/check-input-when-text-is-changed) but none of them work for me...

What should I change?

Comment: You misspelled `</input>`. Try `<input id="sampleInput" type="text" placeholder="sample text" />`.

Comment: Event listeners are not triggered by manually setting the `value` of inputs. You will need to manually trigger the event or call the function directly

Comment: What's `textchange`, `perpertychange` is those is those a new events  ?

Comment: `propertychange` is supported only on IE, `textchange` is [custom](https://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) jQuery event by a plugin

Answer (score 0):

- They're working fine

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"  id="sampleInput">
<button  id="button">click</button>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  var sampleInput = document.getElementById("sampleInput");
  
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    sampleInput.value = "text has been changed!";
  });
  
  sampleInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    console.log("(input) text has been changed!!");
  });
  sampleInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    console.log("(keydown) text has been changed!!");
  });
});
```